# How to assign auto-increment values to a combination of (k,v) pairs of a dict in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the following format. I have made sure the keys are in sorted order, and also so are the values for those keys

```
{67: ['226', '2470', '2517', '2578', '2799', '281', '2905', '3015', '3081', '347', '411'], 68: ['276', '331', '387', '442', '497', '607', '662']}
```

Now, I want to assign an auto-incrementing integer to each combination of a k,v pair.

Example:

```
{(67, 226):1, (67, 2470): 2 ...  (68, 662):18}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the input dict is called `d`:

```
from itertools import count

ls = [(k, n) for k, v in d.items() for n in v]
result = dict(zip(ls, count(1)))
```

Comment: Change it to `enumerate(ls, 1)` (or `enumerate(ls, start=1)` to be explicit) and you can remove the every time work of adding `+ 1` to each `i`, so it's just `{p: i for i, p in enumerate(ls, 1)}`

Comment: Also the order of the dict keys is only guaranteed with python3.7+ so if using an older python3 you should explicitly sort the dictionary items.

Answer (score 1):

This come to my mind to solve your problem

```
data = {67: ['226', '2470', '2517', '2578', '2799', '281', '2905', '3015', '3081', '347', '411'], 68: ['276', '331', '387', '442', '497', '607', '662']}
cont = 1
output_dict = {}
for d in data:
    for value_d in data[d]:
        output_dict[(d, value_d)] = cont
        cont += 1
print(output_dict)
```